# git diff between working copy of the file and its version on another branch

Tags: git

I know a similar question was asked and answered before, but nothing I tried works for me. I'm on my development branch and I want to copy a single file from the head of master branch to my working directory, so I do the following:

```
git checkout origin/master -- <my relative path>
```

The copying works fine, I can see the file timestamp updated. To check the file content I call the `git diff`:

```
git diff <my branch> origin/master -- <my relative path>
```

and I still see some differences between my branch and `origin/master`.

What am I doing wrong?

(git version 1.7.9.5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git diff <my branch> origin/master -- <my relative path>
```

This will diff what has been *committed* to the branches and has nothing to do with your local changes. [the git-diff documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) describes what you want to do:

> ```
> git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>…]
> ```
>
> This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named `<commit>`. You can use HEAD to compare it with
>   the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a
>   different branch.

Try this:

```
git diff origin/master -- <my relative path>
```

Comment: Thanks! The <my branch> removal did the job

Answer (score 3):

`git diff <my branch> origin/master -- <my relative path>` says to diff between *what was last committed to your branch* and origin/master.  From the git-diff man page...

```
   git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the
       named <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a
       branch name to compare with the tip of a different branch.

   git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

You want to diff between the working copy and origin/master.

```
git diff origin/master -- <my relative path>
```

Comment: That's my question - how to diff the current file *before committing* to its version on another branch?

Comment: @HEKTO "Working copy" or "working tree" means the files sitting on your disk, which is what you want to diff against.